# R ggplot: ggpattern and swimmer plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I add a pattern (from `ggpattern` package) to a swimmer bar plot (from `swimplot` package)? The swimmer plot is form of `ggplot`.

Any help with fixing my code would be most helpful.

```
df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3), primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_treatment = c("NA", "S", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 0.39, 3.03)
)

swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
  width = 0.85, color = NA
) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(pattern = additional_treatment, pattern_angle = additional_treatment))
```

When I tried this code it could not add the second layer and said

> "Problem while computing aesthetics."

Comment: First issue which gives rise ti the error you mention: There is no column `additional_therapy` in your data. Perhaps you want `additional_treatment`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to map `additional_treatment` on the `pattern` aes you have to explicitly map on the `x` and `y` aes in `geom_col_pattern` to add a pattern to your swimmer plot:

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)

swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
  width = 0.85, color = NA
) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(study_id, end_yr,
    pattern = additional_treatment, pattern_angle = additional_treatment
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: This causes a new error that says "Error in `geom_col_pattern()`:
Error occurred in the 5th layer.
Caused by error in `if (pat == "regular_polygon" && is.numeric(params$pattern_shape)) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. Any suggestions?